# Unable to Signup and Login using JSON parameter in android

Tags: php, android, json

Login JSON RESPONSE

```
{"VerifiedMember":[{"user_id":"23","first_name":"karan","phone":""}],"success":1,"message":"success"}
```

SignUp JSON RESPONSE

```
{"RegisteredMember":[{"user_id":61,"first_name":"p","phone":"9726068072"}],"success":1,"message":"Registration Successful"}
```

Login Activity Class

```
 public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private static final String TAG = Login.class.getSimpleName();
    private EditText email, password;
    private Button login;
    private TextView signup;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private UserSession session;
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        password        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        login           = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        signup          = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.open_signup);
        progressDialog  = new ProgressDialog(this);
        session         = new UserSession(this);
        userInfo        = new UserInfo(this);

        if(session.isUserLoggedin()){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        login.setOnClickListener(this);
        signup.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void login(final String email, final String password){
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Utils.LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                progressDialog.hide();
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    int intError = jObj.getInt("success");
                    boolean error = (intError > 0) ? true : false;


                        // Check for error node in json
                        if (!error) {
                            // Now store the user in SQLite

                            String uid = jObj.getString("user_id");
                            JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("VerifiedMember");
                            String uName = user.getString("first_name");
                            String email = user.getString("phone");


                            // Inserting row in users table
                            userInfo.setEmail(email);
                            userInfo.setFirstname(uName);
                            userInfo.setUid(uid);
                            session.setLoggedin(true);
                            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                            startActivity(i);



                        } else {
                            // Error in login. Get the error message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("message");
                            toast(errorMsg);


                        }
                 //   }
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    toast("Json error: " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                toast("Unknown Error occurred");
                progressDialog.hide();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AndroidLoginController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void toast(String x){
        Toast.makeText(this, x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.login:
                String uName1 = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String pass  = password.getText().toString().trim();

                login(uName1, pass);
                break;
            case R.id.open_signup:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SignUp.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Signup Activity Class

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = SignUp.class.getSimpleName();
    private EditText username, email, password, gender, bdate, fname, lname;
    private Button signup;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private UserSession session;
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_name);
        gender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gender);
        bdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bdate);

      //  username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_or_phone);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        session = new UserSession(this);
        userInfo = new UserInfo(this);

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String fName = fname.getText().toString().trim();

                String lName = lname.getText().toString().trim();

                String gen = gender.getText().toString().trim();

                String dob = bdate.getText().toString().trim();


                String mail = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String pass = password.getText().toString().trim();



                signup(fName,lName,gen,dob, mail, pass);
            }
        });
    }

    private void signup(final String firstName,final String lastName, final String gend,  final String dobd,final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_signup";
        progressDialog.setMessage("Signing up...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Utils.REGISTER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    int intError = jObj.getInt("success");
                    boolean error = (intError > 0) ? true : false;

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("RegisteredMember");
                        String firstName = user.getString("first_name");
                        String LastName = user.getString("last_name");
                        String email = user.getString("register_nm");
                        String dobd = user.getString("bdate");
                        String gender = user.getString("gender");
                        String password = user.getString("password");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        userInfo.setEmail(email);
                        userInfo.setFirstname(firstName);
                        userInfo.setLastname(LastName);
                        userInfo.setdob(dobd);
                        userInfo.setGender(gender);
                        userInfo.setPassword(password);

                        session.setLoggedin(true);

                        startActivity(new Intent(SignUp.this, MainActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("success");
                        toast(errorMsg);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    toast("Json error: " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                toast("Unknown Error occurred");
                progressDialog.hide();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("first_name", firstName);
                params.put("last_name", lastName);
                params.put("gender",gend);
                params.put("bdate",dobd);
                params.put("phone", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AndroidLoginController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void toast(String x) {
        Toast.makeText(this, x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

UserInfo Class

```
public class UserInfo {
    private static final String TAG = UserSession.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "userinfo";
    private static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "first_name";
    private static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "last_name";
    private static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String KEY_DOB = "bdate";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL_PHONE = "phone";
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context ctx;

    public UserInfo(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname){
        editor.putString(KEY_FIRSTNAME, firstname);
        editor.apply();
    }
     public  void setLastname (String lastname){
        editor.putString(KEY_LASTNAME, lastname);
        editor.apply();
    } public  void setGender (String gender){
        editor.putString(KEY_GENDER, gender);
        editor.apply();
    } public  void setdob (String dob){
        editor.putString(KEY_DOB, dob);
        editor.apply();
    } public  void setPassword (String password) {
        editor.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL_PHONE, email);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void clearUserInfo(){
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getKeyFirstname(){return prefs.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME, "");}
    public String getKeyEmail(){return prefs.getString(KEY_EMAIL_PHONE, "");}
  public String getKeyLastname(){return prefs.getString(KEY_LASTNAME,"");}
  public String getKeyGender(){return prefs.getString(KEY_GENDER,"");}
  public String getKeyDob(){return prefs.getString(KEY_DOB,"");}
  public String getKeyPassword(){return prefs.getString(KEY_PASSWORD,"");}


}
```

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button logout;
    private TextView tvUsername, tvEmail;
    private UserInfo userInfo;
    private UserSession userSession;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userInfo        = new UserInfo(this);
        userSession     = new UserSession(this);
        logout          = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logout);
        tvUsername      = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.key_username);
        tvEmail         = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.key_email);

        if(!userSession.isUserLoggedin()){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
            finish();
        }

        String username = userInfo.getKeyFirstname();
        String email    = userInfo.getKeyEmail();

        tvUsername.setText(username);
        tvEmail.setText(email);

        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                userSession.setLoggedin(false);
                userInfo.clearUserInfo();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
                finish();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

User Session Class

```
public class UserSession {
    private static final String TAG = UserSession.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "login";
    private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN = "isloggedin";
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context ctx;

    public UserSession(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }

    public void setLoggedin(boolean isLoggedin){
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, isLoggedin);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public boolean isUserLoggedin(){return prefs.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, false);}
}
```

SIGNUP PHP CODE

```
<?php
require '../db_connect.php';
require "../classes/class.phpmailer.php";

if(isset($_POST['first_name']) && !empty($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && !empty($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['bdate']) && !empty($_POST['bdate']) && isset($_POST['gender']) && !empty($_POST['gender'])){

$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
//$email=$_POST['email'];
//$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$birthdate=$_POST['bdate'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];

if(is_numeric($register_name))
{
    $email="";
    $phone=$register_name;
    if(!preg_match("/^([0-9][0-9]{9})$/",$phone)) { 
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "invalid phone validation";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }
    $reg_type=1;
    $email_hash="";
}
else{
    $email=$register_name;
    if(!preg_match("/^([_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,5}))|(\d+$)$/",$email)) { 
       $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "invalid email validation";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }
    $phone="";
    $reg_type=2;
    $email_hash = md5(rand(0,1000));
}
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z']+$/",$first_name)) { 
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "invalid firstname validation";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z']+$/",$last_name)) { 
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "invalid lastname validation";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
if(strlen($password) < 6){
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "invalid password validation";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
if(!($gender=='male' || $gender=='female')){
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "invalid gender validation";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;   
}
if(strtotime($birthdate) > strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))){
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "invalid bdate validation";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
function sendOtp($otp, $phone){
        //This is the sms text that will be sent via sms 
        $sms_content = "Your verification code is $otp";

        //Encoding the text in url format
        $sms_text = urlencode($sms_content);

        $arrContextOptions=array(
        "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
                ),
                );

        $api_url = 'https://www.txtguru.in/imobile/api.php?username=candidispin&password=candid@123&source=CANDID&dmobile=91'.$phone.'&message='.$sms_text;

        //Envoking the API url and getting the response 
        $response = file_get_contents($api_url);

        //Returning the response 
        //return $response;
        //header("location:confirmation.php");
    }

    function generateSalt($max = 64) {
        $characterList = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%&*?";
        $i = 0;
        $salt = "";
        while ($i < $max) {
            $salt .= $characterList{mt_rand(0, (strlen($characterList) - 1))};
            $i++;
        }
        return $salt;
    }

    $user_salt = generateSalt(); // Generates a salt from the function above
    $combo = $user_salt . $password; // Appending user password to the salt 
    $hashed_pwd = hash('sha512',$combo); // Using SHA512 to hash the salt+password combo string

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    //echo $date;
    $otp = rand(100000, 999999);
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  

    $sql="insert into user_registration(email,phone,hashed_password,salt,first_name,last_name,birthdate,gender,created_at,register_type,email_hash,is_active,ip_address) values('".$email."','".$phone."','".$hashed_pwd."','".$user_salt."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$birthdate."','".$gender."','".$date."','".$reg_type."','".$email_hash."',1,'".$ip_address."')";
    //echo $sql;

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    $response["RegisteredMember"] = array();    
    $user_id=mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $RegisteredMember['user_id'] = $user_id;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_registration WHERE id =".$user_id;
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
    $RegisteredMember['first_name'] = $result['first_name'];
    $RegisteredMember['phone'] = $result['phone'];
    array_push($response["RegisteredMember"], $RegisteredMember);

    if($reg_type==1){
    $expiration_time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 hours'));
    //echo $expiration_time;

    $sql1="INSERT INTO user_otps (user_id, otp, expiration_time) values ('$user_id','$otp','$expiration_time')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql1)){
    echo sendOtp($otp,$phone);

    }
    }
    else{
        $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from user_authentication");

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
                    // output data of each row

                        $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
                        $company = $row1["Company"];
                        $webemail = $row1["WebEmail"];
                        $username = $row1["Username"];
                        $password = $row1["Password"];
                        $host = $row1["Host"];
                        $port = $row1["Port"];

                        $mail   = new PHPMailer; // call the class 
                        $mail->IsSMTP();  
                        $mail->Host = $host; //Hostname of the mail server
                        $mail->Port = $port; //Port of the SMTP like to be 25, 80, 465 or 587
                        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; //Whether to use SMTP authentication
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                        $mail->Username = $username; //Username for SMTP authentication any valid email created in your domain
                        $mail->Password = $password; //Password for SMTP authentication
                        //$mail->AddReplyTo($email, $name); //reply-to address
                        $mail->SetFrom($webemail, $company); //From address of the mail
                        // put your while loop here like below,
                        $mail->Subject = "Verification Email"; //Subject od your mail
                        $mail->AddAddress($webemail, $company); //To address who will receive this email
                        $mail->AddAddress($email, ""); //To address who will receive this email
                        $url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                        $s_url=$url.'/verify.php?email='.$register_name.'&hash='.$email_hash;
                        $sub =  "Thanks for signing up!<br>Your account has been created<br>Please click this link to verify your account:<br><a href=".$s_url.">Verification Link</a>";
                        $mail->MsgHTML($sub); //Put your body of the message you can place html code here
                        //$mail->AddAttachment("images/asif18-logo.png"); //Attach a file here if any or comment this line, 
                        $send = $mail->Send(); //Send the mails
                        if($send)
                        {
                            $response["success"] = 1;
                            $response["message"] = "Mail sent";

                            // echoing JSON response
                            echo json_encode($response);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $response["success"] = 0;
                            $response["message"] = "Mail not sent";

                            // echoing JSON response
                            echo json_encode($response);
                        }

                }
                else
                {
                            $response["success"] = 0;
                            $response["message"] = "Mail not sent";

                            // echoing JSON response
                            echo json_encode($response);
                }


    }
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Registration Successful";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Parameters are not set";

    echo json_encode($response);
}


?>
```

LOGIN PHP CODE

```
<?php
require '../db_connect.php';
if (isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $myusername = $_POST['username'];
    $mypassword = $_POST['password']; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_registration WHERE (username = '$myusername' or email = '$myusername' or phone = '$myusername')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

    $response["VerifiedMember"] = array();
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $VerifiedMember = array();
        $id=$row['id'];
        $phone=$row['phone'];
        $reg_type=$row['register_type'];
        $stored_salt = $row['salt'];
        $stored_hash = $row['hashed_password'];
        $check_pass = $stored_salt . $mypassword;
        $check_hash = hash('sha512',$check_pass);

        if($check_hash == $stored_hash){

            $VerifiedMember['user_id'] = $id;
            $VerifiedMember['first_name']=$row['first_name'];
            $VerifiedMember['phone']=$row['phone'];
            array_push($response["VerifiedMember"], $VerifiedMember);

         if(!empty($phone)&& $reg_type==1){

             $sql="select * from user_otps where user_id='".$id."'";
             $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
             if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                if($row['verified']==0)
                {
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 0;
                      $response["message"] = "failure";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);

                }
                else
                {   
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 1;
                      $response["message"] = "success";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
             }
         }
         else{
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 1;
                      $response["message"] = "success";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
         }
         //echo json_encode($response);
        }

        else{
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 0;
                      $response["message"] = "invalid";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
    else{
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 0;
                      $response["message"] = "invalid";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
?>
```

Here i am getting error in log 
the error is 
Register Response: {"success":0,"message":"Parameters are not set"}
org.json.JSONException: No value for RegisteredMember

Can anyone help me to Make  Login and Signup using this code

Comment: `Parameters are not set`

Comment: It seems that you haven't sent the appropriate parameters for the API.

Comment: share your php code your code on android side looks ok

Comment: php code is added in question pls check  it and tell me what mistake i have done @sumit

Comment: I have updated your signup php code what I saw wrong in first look try now

Comment: please update android code not php code bcz i m unable to update php code on server so pls can u edit in android code @sumit

Comment: in your Signup activity change this line params.put("phone", email); to params.put("register_nm", email); and try running your code

Comment: yeah itts working bt login is not working

Comment: getting error in LOG
Login Response: 
: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: @sumit pls help me in login also

Comment: share your login response what you're getting the error you're getting is JSON parsing error

Comment: hey i got it actually set wrong parameter like signup not i ts completly works fine bt on eprobelm is there continously progress dialog is running bbt it not go to next activity pls helpo me in that @sumit

Comment: @sumit please help me how to go next activity after succesfully login and register pls helpme

Comment: ok let me have a look

Comment: I have rolled back the latest edit to this question, as it appeared to be a completely new question, which would invalidate the answers give below. Please ask a new question. If you are blocked from asking new questions, then [please read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: Relating to some of the phrases in your prior edit, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("RegisteredMember");
```

is wrong as "RegisteredMember" is an array not object as per your Signup response JSON.

Next thing, it is clear that you got an error  **{"success":0,"message":"Parameters are not set"}** and that JSON doesn't have "RegisteredMember", hence the exception.

So, you can check if the value is present in the json or not as

```
    if(your_json_object.has("RegisteredMember")){
        //Get the JSONArray, take a loop and get individual objects
    }
```

and proceed.

**EDIT**

As far as I remember you had JSONException initially and you didn't get "RegisteredMember" array in your response. So being based on that you can follow the below code.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

            int success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
            String message = jsonObject.getString("message");

            if(jsonObject.has("RegisteredMember")){
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("RegisteredMember");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject regMemberObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String phone = regMemberObject.getString("phone");
                    String firstName = regMemberObject.getString("first_name");
                    int userID = regMemberObject.getInt("user_id");
                }   
            }
            //Similar with the login Json as it too has same format
```

I didn't check your code. I am just giving a generic solution. You will have specific format of response Json & will parse the json in the same way. In case of some error, the server may not send you the same format of json so you there is a change that you may get an exception. So verify & parse the json. **.has(String)** is to verify initially so that you won't get exception later on.

Comment: can u edit in my code bcz i m new in this area so pls help me @Subhechhu Khanal

Comment: Here i have update all code and questiopn so please help me to solve this issue  @Subhechhu Khanal

Comment: Yeah I would love to help you. Can you post the exception one more time please? @KaranIsrani

Comment: Login Response: {"VerifiedMember":[{"user_id":"64","first_name":"samle","pho‌​ne":""}],"success":1‌​,"message":"success"‌​}   @Subhechhu Khanal

Comment: yeah I got login response & sign up response, you had an exception right when the request fails and you get failed response json. Post that too I will help with parsing for all

Comment: nothing get any false response just wtever geti posted here bro @Subhechhu Khanal

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to your code.

And parse your response as below:

```
try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
            int intError = jObj.getInt("success");
            Boolean error = (intError < 0) ? true : false;

            if (!error){
                // user successfully logged in
                // Create login session
                session.setLogin(true);
                JSONArray verifiedMember = jObj.optJSONArray("VerifiedMember");
                for (int i =0;i<verifiedMember.length();i++){
                    JSONObject rootObj = verifiedMember.getJSONObject(i);
                    String userId = rootObj.getString("user_id");
                    String first_name = rootObj.getString("first_name");
                    String email = rootObj.getString("phone");
                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(first__name, email);
                }
                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: can u edit in my code pls @sumit  i am not getting exactly  pls request uh help me

Comment: @KaranIsrani use this to hide progress dialog before moving to new activity

Comment: share the response you're getting and use the updated code

Comment: Login Response: {"VerifiedMember":[{"user_id":"64","first_name":"samle","phone":""}],"success":1,"message":"success"}  @sumit getting this response bt not going to next activity

Comment: your response is not a valid json you must be getting some JSON exception

Comment: example pls @sumit

Comment: why are using array to send your user details?? have a look at this link and change your login.php response accordingly:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value 1 at success of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to boolean    Getting this error while using that code @sumit

Comment: i m not php developer my frnd make it for me @sumit

Comment: yeah instead of 1 use true or false to show success or failure in your php\

Comment: have a look at the link i sent you that's exactly what you need just change the parameters and table name in it nothing else

Comment: I m using this  int intError = jObj.getInt("success");
                    boolean error = (intError > 0) ? true : false;  INSTEAD OF boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("success")  @sumit

Comment: can u help me pls its urgent for me bro @sumit

Comment: share your updated code and correct login response. the response you have shared above doesn't contain error field

Comment: I hv updated Logi Activity Class pls check it @sumit  here in thi code i get Login response success bt not going to new activity

Comment: are you still getting the JSON exception??

Comment: Login Response: {"VerifiedMember":[{"user_id":"23","first_name":"karan","phone":""}],"success":1,"message":"success"}  @sumit

Comment: how come you're not getting error while parsing your response?? your verified member is JSONarray. you should get JSON exception. try putting a log inside if to check if it is properly executing or not

Comment: please sir help me how to go new activity after login and  register succefully @sumit

Comment: Here i have update all code and questiopn so please help me to solve this issue @sumit